# How to get or create credentials from authenticated user in django-allauth

Tags: django, google-api, google-oauth, django-allauth

I think I might be missing something obvious, but I cannot figure out the answer to my question.

I have setup `django-allauth` on my project, added Google auth, enabled the API, ran the server, and successfully used the app for authentication.

**Here's where I'm getting stuck:**

Once the user is authenticated, I'm wanting the user to be able to view their calendar but I cannot figure out how to build the credentials using the credentials of the already authenticated user.

I know that in order to get the calendar, I have to run:

```
service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)
calendar = service.calendars().get(calendarId='primary').execute()
print(calendar['summary'])
```

but I cannot figure out how to build the value for `credentials`

Any help would be so greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to find the answer.

1. `django-auth` creates an instance of a `SocialToken` when a user is authenticated.
2. That token can be found by passing `request.user` to the model object's `get` method.
3. Once you have the token, the token's fields are passed to the parameters of the constructor to create the credential object that is necessary for the `build` function.

#### Example:

```
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials

social_token = SocialToken.objects.get(account__user=request.user)
creds = Credentials(token=social_token.token,
                    refresh_token=social_token.token_secret,
                    client_id=social_token.app.client_id,
                    client_secret=social_token.app.secret)
service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)
calendar = service.calendars().get(calendarId='primary').execute()
```